# Function keys on Dell studio require tapping, rather than long hold

Tags: windows-7, laptop, function-keys

The function keys on my Dell Studio 1558 also double as OEM keys to alter LCD brightness, and up/down the volume.

I have to hold Fn and tap the desired key (e.g. brightness up) to increment a change; is there anything I can download from the Dell site, or even third party, that will let me **hold** the desired key down and have it increment (so I don't have to tap)?

//
Windows 7 - Dell Studio 1558

Comment: +1 I have the same problem and I never realized that it was so annoying to tap against long hold ! until you mentioned :)

Comment: ha, sorry :) My old laptop used to hold and it was so easy. And hardware volume slider too. I miss it lol :)